# What should be used: "leave" vs "leaving"

Tags: past-tense

I am confused about which one should I choose:

> We noticed him **leave** the house.
>
> We noticed him **leaving** the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical, with nearly the same meaning, but they have different grammatical structures, which could slightly alter the meaning.

In

> We noticed him leave the house,

what we noticed is the (meaning of) the clause "him leave the house", which is a subordinated version of the sentence "He left the house" - it was the whole event of "He left the house" that we noticed.

In

> We noticed him leaving the house,

what we noticed ws "him leaving the house", which is not a clause, but a noun phrase ("him") post-modified by an adjectival phrase "leaving the house".

In most cases the meaning is the same, and you can use either. If you want to find a difference, the second puts more emphasis on "him", rather than on the whole event; but the difference is very slight.

Answer (score 3):

*Notice* is a sense perception verb, like *see, hear, watch,* etc. 
These verbs have several interesting characteristics; [one of them is that they can take](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+sense+verbs+infinitive+gerund) 
**either** an infinitive complement clause (without *to*)

- *I saw/heard/noticed/watched him **leave** the house.*

**or** a gerund complement clause

- *I saw/heard/noticed/watched him **leaving** the house.*

with no difference in meaning.

This is not normally true for verbs that take complements; but sense verbs are very common and participate in a number of idiomatic constructions, so they have more affordances than other verbs.